# Replace some string in some phrases using a dictionary of strings in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains some values

```
color=[black, white,....]
```

a have a lot of strings (in one array) that contains a lot of this colors and I need to replace them with the letter C.
So for example

```
"this is a phrase and it contains Blue"
```

must be

```
"this is a phrase and it contains C"
```

I also need that for lowercase color ... (In the dictionary the first letter is capitalized.

This is my code but it doesn't work well

```
for item in json_data:

    count_tot=count_tot+1;
    for color in attributes_dictionary:
        if color in item["title"]:
            item["title"]=item["title"].replace(color,"{"+color+"}\_C")
            print(item["title"])
```

Comment: Clarify doesn't work well. It's slow? It's buggy?

Comment: you've mentioned you have a dictionary, but the variable color holds a list in your example.

Comment: @AndrejPalicka sorry for the mistake... I have corrected the code to be more clear :D...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join all the elements in the color list with `|` as delimiter and pass it as regex in `re.sub` function. `(?i)` helps to do case-insensitive match and `\b` helps to match an exact word.

```
import re
color=['black', 'white', 'Blue']
s = "this is a phrase and it contains Blue"
print re.sub(r'(?i)\b(?:'+'|'.join(color)+r')\b', 'C', s)
```

To get the output mentioned in the comment, you need to use capturing group.

```
print re.sub(r'(?i)\b('+'|'.join(color)+r')\b', r'{\1}_C', s)
```

Comment: It looks so fast... And if I have to tag the color??? so for example blue must be {blue}\_C instead of only C, how can I do?

Comment: you must escape the colors! `'|'.join(re.escape(c) for c in color)`

Comment: I think colors won't contain any special chars.